# No browsers will load web pages

Tags: windows-7, networking, browser

So I've got a netbook that just refuses to actually load a web page; any page. Chrome, FireFox, IE7. IE8. It sits there and tries and tries, then nothing. If you're lucky and hit reload 15-20 times, you might get the page, but nothing works after that. I've ran Hijack this, and nothing abnormal comes up (I'm a minimalist). I've checked proxy settings, all communication configuration, tried removing the router from the equation completely. My friend's laptop hops on and works fine, fast as ever.

Today I noticed that Windows 7 had downloaded some updates, so clearly there is a connection being made, just not happening in the browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Try pinging a website: ping www.google.com, for example, in the command prompt. Then report back

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I can think of (If you need any more details on any point/how to fix, please say in comments):

1. Incorrect DNS settings - but not likely due to "sometimes" working. If this is the case, go to network connections, right click the connection and check DNS settings - either go to automatic or copy the settings from another computer that is working.
2. Could be a virus/malware - unlikely, but you can never rule it out.
3. Check hosts file - `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and see if there is any entries other than the localhost ones.
4. Finally the most likely - bad drivers. Sometimes Windows update downloads driver updates, whilst they do checking, sometimes bad ones can slip in - Try going to `Computer Management` > `System Tools` > `Device Manager` and select the network device then right click and choose `Properties`, go to the `Driver` tab and choose `Roll Back`.

If the above doesn't work, try going to the manufacturer's website of the network device and download the latest update / drivers as hopefully this will fix it.

All the above is assuming it was working at some point - if it wasn't, please say.

Comment: Okay, so starting in safe mode with networking has the web working just fine. Virus scans are clean. HJT log is clean. What else can I look for?